# Is the phrase "Because so" grammatically allowed?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Gary was a man knowledgeable about basic hygiene. **Because so**, he was always thorough when washing his hands.

Would the above phrase "because so" be grammatically allowed?

According to the logic in my head, it should be allowed because:

> A). The phrase "**And so**" and "**And thus**" are interchangeable. Therefore, "**so**" and "**thus**" can have similar meaning.
>
> B). The phrase "**Because of that**" and "**Because of thus**" are interchangeable. Therefore, "**that**" and "thus" can have similar meaning.
>
> C). If above A). and B). are true, then "**that**" and "**so**" should be interchangeable in the phrase "**Because of that**", resulting in "**Because of so**" being grammatically allowed.
>
> D). Since "**Because of so**" is, for a lack of a better description, 'wordy' in the mouth especially when phrased as "**and because of so**", the shorter phrase "**because so**" should be an acceptable substitute.

At this point, I honestly can't tell if my logic is correct or if I'm doing logical gymnastics, especially when it comes to D). And so, I would really appreciate any help in figuring out if my logic is flawed or not and whether "because so" is or is not grammatically allowed.

Comment: *Because of thus* is not grammatical, and it certainly is not interchangeable with *because of that*. Nothing that you wrote in **B)** is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid you are doing logic gymnastics. I’ve done obscure-language-solving, and your logic would be welcome there. Unfortunately, English is rarely cut and dried. In all these cases, you’ve extrapolated from a phrase, and assumed, much like in algebra, that since a * b = 80 and a * c = 80, a = c.

Unfortunately, it is not the same with English; just because ‘and’ + ‘so’ = ‘and’ + ‘thus’, does *not* mean that ‘so’ = ‘thus’ in all situations; they can have very different meanings.

In particular, ‘so’ has a multitude of meanings; it can mean ‘thus’, but it can also be used to mean ‘to such a great extent’, as in

> Her playing was so quick that I could barely see the movements of her fingers.

Or it can mean ‘in order to’, as in

> They run as fast as they can, so that they will win.

‘Because of thus’ is not a phrase I have seen anywhere else, I’m afraid, and Google yields no real results. *However*, whether or not it means the same as ‘because of that’ (and I’m tempted to say that it *might*), does not mean that ‘that’ and ‘thus’ mean the same thing.

‘Thus’ is used to meaning ‘therefore’ or ‘as a result’, as in:

> He accepted her offer, thus becoming proud owner of a stuffed porcupine.

‘That’, however, has a multitude of meanings. It can refer to a specific thing, possibly previously mentioned, as in:

> That’s an excellent idea.

Or it can express a wish,

> Oh, that he would come back to me.

Or it can be used to identify something:

> That’s my friend over there.

And many, many, many more possible meanings besides.

Finally, to the last point — ‘because of [word]’ or ‘and because of [word]’ does not become ‘because [word]’, even if it does sound wordy. This is because ‘because of’ is one complete preposition; you need both parts in order to properly use it.

So I’m afraid you have been doing logic gymnastics. Hope this helps!